# Getting the id of recently updated hasMany relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I am working on a project where I need to update two related models in my controller. Below, I am creating one transaction record for a user that can have many transactions. After that, I need access to the id of the recently created transaction, but since thats hasMany relationship, laravel is throwing an error.

UserModel

```
public function transaction()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Transaction');
}
```

Controller

```
    $user->transaction()->create([
        ...
        ...
    ])->save();

    $devUnit = new DevUnit();
    $devUnit->transaction_id = $user->transaction()->id; //this throws an error
```

Error

`Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, totally misread your question.

Save the result of the `create` method to a variable to get access to the populated model with the ID.

```php
$transaction = $user->transaction()->create([
    //
]);

$timeshareUnit = new TimeshareUnit();
$timeshareUnit->transaction_id = $transaction->id;
```

Comment: ```$transaction = $user->transaction()->create([
    //
])->save();``` Calling `save` returns a boolean.... so calling `id` after that throws an undefined error

Comment: Copied a bit too much. You don't need the `save()` method when you use `create()`.

Comment: Still getting an undefined property

Comment: Weird. It works for me. Does the column `id` exist in the `transactions` table? What does `create()` return?